# How to retrieve a model with a filter on one of it's hasMany relationships?

Tags: laravel, laravel-lighthouse

I'm trying to get a model and also add filter to one of it's hasMany relationships.

Let's say I have two models. One of is `Location` and other one is the `LocationAnalytic`.

`Location` model hasMany `LocationAnalytic` class. So when I want to retrieve a Location by Id, it returns all of the `Location` data and also returns a `LocationAnalytic` data as array. In my case a Location model can be related to thousands of LocationAnalytic model.

My need is to get the `Location` model but also get only related `LocationAnalytic` data that has filtered by the given filters. By this way I will get the same `Location` data and also get only couple of `LocationAnalytic` data with it in the same response.

It is similar to whereHas directive but it will not check for existence, it will only filter relationship of a model.

My Query will be like the following;

```
query($id:Int!) {
    location (id: $id) {
        id
        parent_id
        name
        admin_level
        country
        analytic {
            id
            category_id
            total_listings_count
            new_listings_count
            expired_listings_count
            created_at
        }
    }
}
```

And my filters will something like the following

```
{
  "location_idid": 100075,
  "analytics": {
      "AND": [
          { "column": "CATEGORY_ID", "operator": "EQ", "value": 390005 }
      ]
  }
}
```

Comment: did the answer below work for you ? if so, please mark it as The answer to close your question

Answer (score 2):

Use the second parameter of the with() method to filter a relation

```php
$locationId;

$filter = ['field' => 'category_id', 'operator' => '=', 'value' => 390005];

$location = Location::with('locationAnalytics', function($locationAnQuery) use ($filter) {
    $locationAnQuery->where($filter['field'], $filter['operator'], $filter['value']);
})->find($locationId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it gives a good point to start with but I was looking for an answer in graphql and lighthouse package.

Answer (score -1):

For now best solution I found is;

By using @method directive, I was able to create a method that gets all the filters and returns result.

https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#method

I added a new field named `filteredAnalytic` to my `Location` type

```
type Location {
    id: Int
    filteredAnalytic(category_id: Int, tenure_id: Int, type_group_id: Int, contact_type_id: Int, source_id: Int, age_group_id: Int, room_count: Int): LocationAnalytic @method
}
```

I have added a new method with `filteredAnalytic` name to `Location` model

```
public function filteredAnalytic($category_id, $tenure_id, $type_group_id, $contact_type_id, $source_id, $age_group_id, $room_count)
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LocationAnalytic::class)
            ->where('category_id',$category_id)
            ->where('tenure_id', $tenure_id)
            ->where('type_group_id', $type_group_id)
            ->where('contact_type_id', $contact_type_id)
            ->where('source_id', $source_id)
            ->where('age_group_id', $age_group_id)
            ->where('room_count', $room_count)
            ->first();
    }
```

By this I can create a query like the following and able to pass filter to a model relation.

```
query($coordinates:CoordinatesInput, $category_id:Int, $tenure_id:Int, $type_group_id:Int, $contact_type_id:Int, $source_id:Int, $age_group_id:Int, $room_count:Int) {
    locations (coordinates: $coordinates) {
        id
        parent_id
        name
        admin_level
        country
        filteredAnalytic (category_id: $category_id, tenure_id: $tenure_id, type_group_id: $type_group_id, contact_type_id:$contact_type_id, source_id:$source_id, age_group_id:$age_group_id, room_count:$room_count) {
            id
            location_id
            created_at
        }
    }
}
```

with filters,

```
{
   "coordinates" : {
      "lat": 41.671,
      "lng": 27.9714
  },
  "category_id": 30003,
  "tenure_id": 10001,
  "type_group_id": 310001,
  "contact_type_id": 110002,
  "source_id": 40002,
  "age_group_id": 300001,
  "room_count": null
}
```